# Combining two Regular expressions into a single one using Vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I had two regular expressions which are mentioned below .

Regex 1.

```
^\d{9}_[a-zA-Z]{1}_(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{3}_[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}(?:_[0-9a-zA-Z]*)?
```

using this I am checking string.

> 999999999_A_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription

if any of this pattern got failed let say

> 999999999_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription

I need to notify second part got missed for this I am using regex 2.

Regex 2.

```
^\d{9}_^[a-zA-Z]$_(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{4}_^[0-9]{3}$_[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}$_[0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

I tried splitting regex one and string into groups and comparing them. i am using Regex.Match method in vb.net even if my string contains

> 999999999_AB_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription

it is giving result as success.so I wrote regex 2 for exact match. But I need to combine these two regular expressions and make it into a single one. I am splitting regex 2 and string comparing them using Regex.Match method in vb.net which is working but I don't want to maintain two regex expressions.

Considered Match: 9

> 99999999_A_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription

if any thing is missing from the above string like

> 999999999_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription

(or) if anything is other than above format like

> 999999999_AB_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription

which are considered as mismatch I need to find which part is missing and I should notify it to the user

MisMatch:

> 999999999_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription,999999999_AB_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription,999999999_AB_12.10.20_010_2q_somedescription,999999999_AB_12.10.2015_01_2q_somedescription,999999999_AB_12.10.2015_010_2_somedescription,9999_AB_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription

Comment: Can you describe in generic term what string is considered a match and what is not? A few examples will also help. It's hard to get the pattern from your question.

Comment: Considered Match: 999999999_A_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription if any thing is missing from the above string like  999999999_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription (or)  if anything is other than above format like 999999999_AB_12.10.2015_010_2q_somedescription  which are considered as missmatch  I need to find which part is missing and I should notify it to the user

Comment: Please edit the question, don't leave it in the comment. Also a few more matches and non-matches would help

Answer (score 0):

You should use named group to get the value of the part that can change. For example:

```
\d{9}_(?<X>[a-zA-Z]{1})_(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{3}_[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}(?:_[0-9a-zA-Z]*)?
```

Now in VB.NET you can check the value of the capture group X in your match. You can then use `if` or `switch` to do whatever you want.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer I am new to Regular expressions